# Create a month.name index in r by reading dates

Tags: r, date

I have the following data frame called "CNO_2020_Monthly". I have only 3 months populated on this data frame.

```
      Var1 Freq
1 Oct 2020    4
2 Nov 2020    5
3 Dec 2020    6
```

I want to create a month.name index. For that, I used the code below:

```
CNO_2020_Monthly$MonthInd <- month.name[CNO_2020_Monthly$Var1]
```

The result came like that:

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", 
"Dec 2020"), class = "factor"), Freq = 4:6, MonthInd = c("January", 
"February", "March")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

October, November, and december come as "January", "February", "March". Is that any way to create a month.name() based on the contents of the field instead of creating a sequence - meaning, that the month.name for October 2020 will be "october"?

*Additional information*
I have additional data frames that I will merge with the one above based on the month.name - that is why I don't what to create manyally the month.name index but find a way to do it using logic.

Comment: Convert Var1 to date class then extract month name, or just use substring.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Convert Var1 to yearmon class and then format it using %B:

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(CNO$Var1), "%B")
## [1] "October"  "November" "December"
```

**2)** Alternately extract the month, match it to month.abb and then use that index into month.name.  Note that (1) will also work in non-English locales but this one only works in English.  This alternative only uses base R.

```
month.name[match(substr(CNO$Var1, 1, 3), month.abb)]
## [1] "October"  "November" "December"
```

### Note

```
CNO <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:3, levels = c("Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", 
"Dec 2020"), class = "factor"), Freq = 4:6), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

`lubridate` has a *month year* function `my`

```
library(lubridate)

cbind(CNO_2020_Monthly, MonthInd = format(my(CNO_2020_Monthly$Var1), "%B"))
      Var1 Freq MonthInd
1 Oct 2020    4  October
2 Nov 2020    5 November
3 Dec 2020    6 December
```